# sidekiq not processing job, application-wide, on jruby

Tags: sidekiq, jrubyonrails

I need to be able to run 'jruby' alongside with 'sidekiq' in effort to add parallelism ability to my old web application, which was originally written using MRI ruby.
I'm now running it on jruby 1.7.16.1, rails 3.2.8, and mysql 5.5, the same like other applications I developed on the same machine and hosting the app on 'puma' web server.

everything seems to be working just fine, all UIs functioning correctly.
except one important thing that I really need to achieve, sidekiq doesn't seem to process job, exclusively for above mentioned migrated web application.

I believe I set up everything correctly following ryan bates'railscast ep366: http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq.

strangely enough, you guess what, I surprisingly found it's however working when I run sidekiq in another small test project, using the same rails 3.2.8 and with the same small subset of gems from above big application. That's also tested on the same machine (Macbook Pro/OSX 10.8).
,where I managed to spin up redis-server running and had sidekiq automatically picked up jobs to process in the background perfectly.

here is the error I always got every time I'm trying to run sidekiq by the command "bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml"

```
2015-01-19T14:29:51.072Z 6098 TID-43g INFO: Running in jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392) 2014-10-28 4e93f31 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_71-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
2015-01-19T14:29:51.073Z 6098 TID-43g INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2015-01-19T14:29:51.074Z 6098 TID-43g INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org/pro
2015-01-19T14:29:51.074Z 6098 TID-43g INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2015-01-19T14:29:51.087Z 6098 TID-4dg ERROR: Actor crashed!
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:
    java.lang.Thread.setName(java/lang/Thread.java:1161)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606)
    RUBY.name_current_thread(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:164)
    RUBY.initialize(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:61)
    RUBY.create(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
2015-01-19T14:29:51.089Z 6098 TID-4dg ERROR: thread crashed
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:
    java.lang.Thread.setName(java/lang/Thread.java:1161)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606)
    RUBY.name_current_thread(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:164)
    RUBY.initialize(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:61)
    RUBY.create(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16.1@rails3.2.8/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
```

one error that sounds very critical and eventually hold off the ongoing process is undoubtedly the line that says "thread crashed". after that all sidekiq process seems to hang.

*Here, I'd like to share my Gemfile, in case it'd help give you guys more clues:*

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
gem 'roo','1.12.1'
gem 'jdbc-mysql', platform: :jruby
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', platform: :jruby
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.2'

gem 'haml', '3.1.7'
gem 'puma'

gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'devise-async', '0.5.0'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.8'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.4'
gem 'cocoon', '1.1.1'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.3.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'mechanize', '2.5.1'
gem 'delayed_job', '3.0.4'
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.0'
gem 'spreadsheet', '0.6.4.1'
gem 'geocoder', '1.1.6'
gem 'whenever', '0.8.2'
gem 'american_date', '1.0.0'
gem 'money','5.1.1'
gem 'rets','0.5.1'
gem 'haversine','0.3.0'
gem 'sidekiq','3.2.2'
gem 'sinatra'

group :assets do
  gem 'stylus', '0.7.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
end
```

*My config/sidekiq.yml file:*

```
---
:concurrency: 2
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: log/sidekiq.log
:verbose: true
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
  - [myqueue, 2]
```

and the final piece is the worker class itself:

*workers/pygments_worker.rb*

```
class PygmentsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(snippet_id)
    puts "performing lengthy task #{snippet_id}"
    sleep 60
  end
end
```

any idea how to get this to work? your advice would be very much appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you fix it?

Comment: @AugustoPedraza I managed to fix that. By then, I had sidekiq v.3.2.2 in my Gemfile and I didn't specify the version of celluloid gem (a sidekiq dependency). So, I was automatically locked at celluloid v.0.16.0 at that time.
Afterward, I later made some changes as to have sidekiq v.3.2.5 and celluloid v.0.15.2 locked in my Gemfile and it seemed to work. I think the problem I encountered was much about compatibility between sidekiq and celluloid gems.